# SurfaceView lags if in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` in a `ScrollView`. Whenever I try to scroll, the `SurfaceView` always lags a bit behind leaving black seams where it doesn't cover the space where it has to be.

My code for the `SurfaceView` is:

```
<SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_stats_hourly_surface_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_stats_hourly_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/outline" />
```

How can I set the `SurfaceView` to keep up with the scrolling to stop the black seams from appearing?

I should also mention that I started a new project with a blank activity with a `ScollView` and a `SurfaceView` inside it with the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) on ICS and above, aka API 14+.

Answer (score 1):

Try [setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29)
for the container of your SurfaceView